# I don't get the blocks I mine in Amplified mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've gone into Amplified survival, and I tried to mine some blocks. I wasn't getting anything, so I thought it was just block lag. But I waited 5-10 mins every time, still nothing happened. Now it's been like 15 minutes and still no blocks appear.

I'm 100% sure Im in the right gamemode, too. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you checked `/gamerule doTileDrops`? It is very similar to its sister gamerule `doMobLoot` but instead of controlling mob drops, it controls whether or not blocks drop items when destroyed in any way. Executing `/gamerule doTileDrops true` will set the gamerule back to its original state. If this works for you, comment on this and I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

As caucow said, first make sure that you do `/gamerule doTileDrops true`. After you do that, and it still doesn't work, make sure that you are using the correct tool to break the block :P. If that doesn't work, try and re-install Minecraft (I know it seems kinda lame, but hey, it works (sometimes)). If it still doesn't work, ask [these people](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/emails/new).